# how to count the lines of a text files

Tags: java, while-loop

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Practices {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
```

This is my text file:

To be or not to be that is
the question
what about now
so be it

```
Scanner input =new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Charlie/workspace/Summerexercises/src/hamlet.txt"));
            int countwords=0;
            int countlines=0;
            int countchar=0;

            while(input.hasNext())
            {
                String word = input.next();
                countwords++;
            }
            System.out.println("total words= "+ countwords);
```

this is the while loop, which count lines, but doesn't work propertly

```
while(input.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String lines= input.nextLine();
                    countlines++;
                }
                System.out.println("total lines= "+ countlines);




                input.close();
              }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't mind having all the file in memory: `int countLines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset).size();`...

Comment: *"...doesn't work properly."* is a very vague statement. You are going to have to be more precise than that. Does it throw an exception? Does it give the wrong output? What does it do that is wrong?

Comment: NO it compile well and show that my text file has 16 words and 0 lines.

Comment: I guess that your `input` variable is consumed on the first loop. So, when you want to count the lines, it already has traversed the file, giving you 0 lines.

Comment: I found the problem. It shows an exception after I debugged. I have resolved. Thanks. Sorry for the stupid question. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Loop will count the number of lines **

```
int count = 0;
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    count++;
    scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: what actually is the difference between the logic of your code and the OP's code?

Comment: Scanner input2 =new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Charlie/workspace/Summerexercises/src/hamlet.txt"));
     while(input2.hasNextLine())
     {
      countlines++;
      input2.nextLine();
     }

this works for me too!!

Comment: yep @CharlieMelCop because you first scannerObject got consumer while counting the number of words you need fresh instance of scanner to iterate the file again

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)

```
LineNumberReader  lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/Users/Charlie/workspace/Summerexercises/src/hamlet.txt")));
lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(lnr.getLineNumber());
lineNumberReader.close();
```

Source : http://www.technicalkeeda.com/java/how-to-count-total-number-of-lines-of-file-using-java

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from the beginning of the file again. By the time the first loop ends, you will be pointing to the EOF, so no lines are counted in the second loop. try commenting out the first loop and run this program.

Answer (score 0):

In your first loop you consume all your Scanner content, the second loop gets never executed. Do this:

```
Scanner input =new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Charlie/workspace/Summerexercises/src/hamlet.txt"));
int countwords=0;
int countlines=0;
int countchar=0;
while(input.hasNext())
{
    String word = input.next();
    countwords++;
}
System.out.println("total words= "+ countwords);
input.close();
input =new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Charlie/workspace/Summerexercises/src/hamlet.txt"));
while(input.hasNextLine())
{
    String lines= input.nextLine();
    countlines++;
}
System.out.println("total lines= "+ countlines);
input.close();
```